# Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

```
resources :users do
  get :save_delete, :on => :member
  get :question_form, :on => :member
  post :question_send, :on => :member
  resources :comments
end
```

After send and POST to my server I got this error in the log:

```
#Started POST "/users/1/question_send"
#ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/1/question_send")

rake routes # works fine, no errors
```

Comment: You most likely should be using another resource here.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely haven't restarted your server. The routing code looks fine.

However, I agree with @mathepic - your resource seems rather odd. There may be something we don't know, but unless you have a really really really good reason for these `question_form` and `question_send` member routes, you should probably think about doing this some other (and more Rails-y) way.